# SSRS Excel Protecting WorkBooks

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008 R2.

I want to generate a protected excel workbook so report users can reference it but cannot accidentally change it.

ALternatively I would accept being able to protect individual columns.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible with SSRS 2008 R2. A quick search results in a [msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/98f52748-4f89-4623-a638-c0094c4c29ef) corroborating this.

Alternatives I can think of, some of which a bit "heavy" though:

1. Use SSIS to fill an existing XLS file that has protection.
2. Export to XML, followed by custom post-processing using XSLT to transform to Office2007 format.
3. Write a [custom rendering extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to do your own Excel-rendering.